# Amazon Alexa's card system and Flask-Ask

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit

Ok im new to Alexa skill development but its going well, my skill is coming on well however, id like to add some more content in the form of a card. The data id like to populate the card with is in the form of a list. So I thought id try passing the list directly (didnt think it would work but worth a shot). There is nothing in the docs that explains passing lists to the card system. Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

The intent function looks like this:

```
@ask.intent('TopTenCounties')
def top_ten():
    top_countries = get_top_ten_countries()
    stats = []
    for item in top_countries[1]:
        stat = str(item[0]) + ' ' + str(item[1])
        stats.append(stat)
    msg = "The top ten countries are, {}".format(top_countries[0])
    return statement(msg).standard_card(title='Top Ten Usage Stats:',
                       text=stats,
                       large_image_url='url.com/img.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's cards only take text, no other rich format is currently supported (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/providing-home-cards-for-the-amazon-alexa-app). What's happening here is that the list is being converted to string automatically. You probably want to make your own little function to do it yourself so you have more fine control on how it's done.

```
def lst2str(lst, last='and'):
    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(lst[0:-1]) + ' ' + last + ' ' + lst[-1]
```